# chroot access to www folder

Tags: ssh, chroot

here is the setup
sshd_config:

```
Match User sftp
    ChrootDirectory /chroot/sftp
```

I connect just fine to the folder

```
/chroot/sftp
```

However I cannot access the website developer folder due to it being outside the scope of the defined chrootdirectory

```
/usr/lib/apache2/htdocs
```

How can I access this directory? Is it possible to define the access through sshd_config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the behavior you're asking for when you use chroot. I don't think you can fix this in the sshd_config, but there are two options you might consider:

1) Change Apache's document root so that it lives inside /chroot/sftp. This would be done in your Apache config.
2) Mount the htdocs directory in /chroot/sftp. Something like this:

mount --bind /usr/lib/apache2/htdocs /chroot/sftp

I'm not 100% confident in that command, but the theory is there.

Comment: sorry, I am using SCO Unix.
mount --bind
mount -F lofi
are both not options in my case

Comment: Surely there must be SOME way to hard-link directories in SCO?

Comment: @brianlacy I have looked low and high and SCO UNIX does not support many fs types. http://docsrv.sco.com:507/en/man/html.ADM/mount.ADM.html